# ¿Cómo repetir cada letra de un string?

Tags: javascript, string, funciones, caracteres

¿Cómo escribo una función que reciba como parámetro un `string`
y devuelve un `string`, en donde cada letra se repita una vez?

Por ejemplo:

```
"hola"
'hola'.repetir() 
retorna "hhoollaa"


funcion repetirCaracteres(){
    //código
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente función toma como parámetro un string y retorna un string con cada carácter del original repetido.

El procedimiento es separar el string en un arreglo de caracteres, repetir cada caracter con el método repeat y unir nuevamente el arreglo como un string.

```javascript
function repeatCharacters(word) {
  const letters = word.split('')
  const repeated = letters.map(letter => letter.repeat(2))
  return repeated.join('')
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: No olvides marcarla como respuesta correcta porfavor.